# Force refresh/reload when user navigates Back and forward again

Tags: javascript, browser, reload

I want to know how i can ensure page reload/refresh when user presses the back button and then presses forward again.?
Please help!

Comment: Possible [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071838/force-reload-refresh-when-pressing-the-back-button)

Answer (score 0):

You can use cookie to set "back button pressed" flag.

eg. jQuery + [jquery cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)

```
    $(document).ready(function($) {
      if ($.cookie("reload") === *YOUR-PAGE-ID*) {

        $.removeCookie("reload");
        location.reload();

      } else if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {

        window.history.pushState("forward", null, "./#forward");

        $(window).on("popstate", function() {
          $.cookie("reload", *YOUR-PAGE-ID*); // set cookie with some page id
        });

      }
    });
```

Since `popstate` is not supported by older browsers you should use [history.js](https://github.com/browserstate/history.js/)

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type='button' onclick="window.location=window.location.href;">
```

demo is at my website http://vitideas.in/stackoverflow/

Comment: This will only refresh current page on button clik. You need to store 'navigation back' state.

Comment: Okay.I didn't get you.you want to track whether the user has refreshed a page?.