# How to force reload when back button is pressed in Nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, reload

I am trying to implement force reload page when back button is pressed in my nodejs application .
I cannot find anything relevant to this . Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance .

Comment: see also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29107229/chrome-41-force-reload-when-pressing-the-back-button?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9071838/force-reload-refresh-when-pressing-the-back-button?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500684/force-refresh-reload-when-user-navigates-back-and-forward-again?rq=1) - all from "Related" links on this page

Comment: note that although you may be using a combined frontend-backend stack with nodejs as the framework, your question is about manipulating browser clients, thus it is only relevant to browser javascript and your solution will exist in your client code